# Faint Line around Video in IE9

Tags: html, css

In this CSS3/HTML5 video example when I click on the stop and pause button IE9 shows a faint line around the video object. Is there any way to remove this line. http://video.stickon.me/css

```
<video width="416" controls autoplay >
<source src="http://www.archive.org/download/BathToyLakeHaweaWaves/hawea_512kb.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="http://www.archive.org/download/BathToyLakeHaweaWaves/hawea.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' >
</video>

video {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 200px 50px 200px 50px;
    box-shadow: #244766 10px 10px 10px;
    transform: rotate(5deg) translate(15px,10px);
}
```

Added [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/yRHgW/) of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to the CSS:

```
outline: 0;
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/yRHgW/1/

Comment: Thanks that seems to fix it. Should have remembered that from doing links in firefox